# Sorting a long list in excel numerically with numbers formatted as non-numeric values mixed in

Tags: excel, list, sorting, numbers

I am trying to sort a large column of numbers in excel. This list contains many blank rows. when I highlight the column and select the sort function, I am only given the option to sort from "A-Z" and not from "smallest to largest" as I wish to sort my list. I am assuming this is because though the list appears to be made solely of numbers, some of the numbers must have been added in another format (such as text) and therefore cannot be sorted from smallest to largest. Unfortunately, though I have searched, I cannot find a way short of re-typing each number on the list (which is not feasible) to determine which numbers are in numeric form and which are not.

I have tried to follow the suggestion found here (http://excel.tips.net/T002922_Sorting_Huge_Lists.html) which recommends typing the number "1" into a blank space in the document, highlighting the data you wish to sort in numeric form, and pasting special with the multiply function so resulting list in a reproduction of your original list formatted solely in numeric form. The problem is that my list contains many blank spaces and using this strategy, all blanks are considered "0" and therefore after the multiplication the data produced has converted all of my blanks to "0". This is unacceptable as "0" is one of the possible numbers in my number set and so confusing blanks with true "0"s cannot happen.

I have also tried to highlight the list and change the formatting via the formatting bar on the home tab to "numbers" from "general" but this has not helped.

Is there another way to either convert this column of numbers to a column of numbers solely in numeric form or to otherwise sort this list from smallest to largest?

OR could there be another reason such as the length of the list (3000 rows long) or the multiple blank spaces that are causing the list not to be able to sort from smallest to largest?

Please keep in mind I am a VERY VERY novice excel coder and cannot use macros. Any suggestions must be basic or well explained in a step by step manner.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you select "Skip Blanks" in the paste special so blanks are not converted to 0?  Without actually seeing your data (or at least a subset of your data), it is difficult to come up with a solution.

Comment: Okay, this trick will combine the link you have above with this link (http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/goto-special-non-blank-cells/).  First, do the step above with the link where you place "1" into a blank cell and copy this cell.  Basically, add a blank row to the top of the data set then select the 3,000 rows (including the blank cell) & press F5->Special, select "Column Differences" and press Ok (only the non-blank rows are selected).  Now, do the Paste Special and select multiple (the blank rows are not converted to "0".

Comment: You could insert something about Occam's Razor here.  No issues with that and a simple "Convert to Number" will probably work.  I was just giving a solution to "avoid the blanks" problem @Mich originally tried.